# Is there the keyword 'with' in Perl?

Tags: perl, with-statement

In this file

https://github.com/csirtgadgets/massive-octo-spice/blob/develop/src/lib/CIF/Observable/Binary.pm,

I was confused by the statement

with 'CIF::Observable';

at line 9.Is there the keyword 'with' in Perl? How it works?

```
package CIF::Observable::Binary;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Mouse;
use Digest::SHA qw/sha256_hex/;

with 'CIF::Observable';

use constant DEFAULT_HASH_TYPE => 'sha256';

has '+otype' => (
default => 'binary',
);  

has 'hash' => (
is      => 'ro',
isa     => 'CIF::Type::Hash',
default => sub { sha256_hex($_[0]->{'observable'}) },
);  

has 'htype' => (
is      => 'ro',
isa     => 'Str',
default => DEFAULT_HASH_TYPE(),
);  

sub process {}
sub understands {
my $self = shift;
my $args = shift;

return unless($args->{'observable'});
return unless($args->{'otype'});
return unless($args->{'otype'} eq 'binary');
return 1;
} 
__PACKAGE__->meta()->make_immutable();

1;
```

Answer (score 6):

The `with` keyword is used by the [`Mouse`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mouse) object system to indicate that the class being defined uses the specified *role*

`Mouse` is a reduced implementation of the `Moose` object system, written primarily to reduce the long compile times that are to be expected with programs based on `Moose`

The way roles are handled in `Mouse` is almost identical to that in `Moose`, and the [`Moose::Role` documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moose::Role) serves for both modules